# Services or system to store project credentials / passwords / users / information

Tags: service, storage

I'm trying to find a service or system that can store information of a project, like (for example a web site project), users of the CMS, FTP, DB giving some examples.

I tried google, with different keywords, but since english isn't my main language I haven't been able to find something.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different options for storing files and data for your projects. If you want a collaborative type environment where you can share your projects (or keep them private) a very popular option is Github (https://github.com). Another service that has a nice set of features is Pantheon (https://www.getpantheon.com/). Hope this helps.